# Temporary lock the resource until goroutine is finished

Tags: rest, go, goroutine

I have a method, which sends HTTP status-code **202 Accepted** as indicator of successful request, and runs another process in it (goroutine). Something like that:

```golang
return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }()
}
```

I want to temporarily lock the resource to prevent multiple execution of goroutine process.

```golang
return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := make(chan bool)

    select {
    case _, unlocked := <-c:
        if unlocked {
            break
        }
    default:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusLocked)
        return
    }

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)
    go func(c chan bool) {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        c <- true
    }(c)
}
```

I'm get **423 Locked** status code always. I think, I don't understand channel yet. May be try to use mutexes?

Comment: `c` is local to each invocation of your function, there is no coordination happening here. You need to use the same channel (or a mutex) for all invocations of the function. Either a global or some other shared state. And the channel doesn't have any elements in it, so it will always go to the default case.

Comment: @Marc, you're talking about defining global variable `c` outside func body?

Comment: Use something else entirely, a channel is the wrong thing to use here, but yes.

Comment: Yeah... Channels confuse me. I tried to use mutex, but I can't check does it locked or not.

Comment: Use a mutex to protect a simple boolean variable. Only lock the mutex to read/set the variable, not while processing.

Comment: You should probably start by trying to understand what a mutex and a channel is. Before you use them. It's not that hard really. A tour of go explains the concepts in s simple manner. Programming by stabbing in the dark and hoping things will work is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not the best solution, but it works:

```golang
func (h *HookHandler) NewEvents() http.HandlerFunc {
    eventsLocker := struct {
        v   bool
        mux *sync.Mutex
    }{
        v:   true,
        mux: &sync.Mutex{},
    }

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if !eventsLocker.v {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusLocked)
            return
        }

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)

        go func() {
            defer eventsLocker.mux.Unlock()
            defer func() { eventsLocker.v = true }()

            eventsLocker.mux.Lock()
            eventsLocker.v = false

            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        }()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to also lock the mutex when reading `eventsLocker.v`, and you should lock/unlock around each individual `v = false` and `v = true` statements.